# Casperjs script how to use regular expression for Form ID?

Tags: casperjs

**Given HTML:**

```html
<form id="profileSetupForm26" action="?x=5Y-M5vRfdujC7zuC5S4Ih-iKzt7c666WKAuQI9XKA0HTB5pnCbGea8k57gawfMKixyxBeUZxK3nyBO6UhTEYuLPttld6WIF94AhgIV8Jlsr8MK9lr-IKLg" method="post" ric:loaded="true">
<div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden">
<input id="profileSetupForm26_hf_0" type="hidden" name="profileSetupForm26_hf_0">
```

**I used below code but it did not worked can you please help me ?, because above form id is changing dynamically.**

**Code:**

```js
this.fillXPath('form#profileSetupForm', {
    '//input[@name="Form"]':    'Hi',}
```

Comment: Thank you !! but it is throwing syntax error after running "casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes a1.js" so what could be problem for error ? Error -> "C:\Desktop>SyntaxError: Parse error" . Code Used -> casper.then(function() {
   this.fillXPath("form[id^='profileSetupForm']"){
          '//*[@id='profileName']':'cbtwl01';    
      
    }, true);

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use regexp in CSS selector, but you can match the begining of an attribute:

```
$("form[id^='profileSetupForm']")
```

will match profileSetupForm26, profileSetupForm27, profileSetupFormWhatEver, ...